# parallel translation within geometrical form with two different heights

Tags: geometry

Please see attached images.
I need a formula for c' and to be honest I have no clue how to proceed with this problem.

The graphic construction of this problem is easy, but I need a formula.

So, when having the "inner form" I add 1cm to each side and connect the lines.

What I need is the mathematical construction for this.

Thanks for any help!
Best,
Jules

[image: Image 1: https://www.wagnerconsult.de/skizze_1.gif]

[image: Image 2: https://www.wagnerconsult.de/skizze_2.gif]

Rephrased to use MathJax:

$a' = a + 2 $

$b' = b + 1 $

$c' = ?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks, I added the MathJax for my question. Please forgive me, as I don't have any clue how to approach $c'$ I could not use MathJax here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c'=c+x$ and $x=1+y$, but:
$$
y:(c-b)=2:a,
\quad\hbox{hence:}\quad
y=2{c-b\over a}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for answering, Aretino!
But I'm sorry, I think I don't get it.

I'm not looking for y, but for the point where the lines of $c'$ and the upper red slant cross. Shall I post another image to express this?

Comment: What you are looking for is my $x=c'-c=1+y$.

Comment: I changed the diagram adding some color, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you! It is clearer! :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry my score is not enough to add a comment , I have a question , I think the problem becomes easy if the answers is ok .
there is a right angles in your image ?

Comment: Nevermind! :) yes, between $a$ and $c$ and $a$ and $b$ are right angles!